# Redis breaks JSON formatting

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I'm storing an array into my redis variable, and I want to print it out like an API, with json. This works fine without redis, but when I converted to redis the output is full of backslashes and pretty print does no longer work.

```
if(!Redis::exists("my_redis")) 
{
    $redis = DB::table("table")->distinct()->where("id", "=", 1)->get();
    Redis::set("my_redis", $redis);
}
else
{
    $redis = Redis::get("my_redis");
}

return response()->json($redis, 200, [], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Again, if no redis exists, it prints the output just fine with pretty print and json etc. Doesn't do that when it's reading from redis, it returns something similar to:

```
"[{\"id\":\"1\"}]"
```

How can this issue be solved?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `$redis` in the first case will be an array (or collection), and a JSON string in the second. If it's a string, you end up double-encoding it when you call `response()->json(...)`

Comment: Try json_encoding it before putting it in redis, then on the way out it will be ready to json_decode.

Comment: Thanks @LawrenceCherone that fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $redis = DB::table("table")->distinct()->where("id", "=", 1)->get();
```

This returns collection try `get()->toJson()` then save it to Redis.

Hope this helps.